# jackson exception in unirest: Serialization Impossible. Can't find an ObjectMapper implementation

Tags: json, serialization, jackson, unirest, objectmapper

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectNode object = mapper.readValue("{\"myjson\":\"string\"}", ObjectNode.class);
HttpResponse<JsonNode> postResponse = Unirest.post("")
    .header("accept", "application/json")
    .body(object)
    .asJson();
```

Causes the runtime exception in the title on the call to body. I'm not sure what to do here, I'm attempting to wrap a json string in a JsonNode object which I'd assume is normal procedure when sending via unirest interface (in the data body).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do it like that. You can't pass ObjectNode into body method. You might implement custom ObjectMapper for that type. But I don't think that it's what you want.

Perhaps you can do something like this:

```
.header("Content-Type", "application/json")
.body(mapper.writeValueAsString(object))
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [the docs](https://kong.github.io/unirest-java/#requests) you need to set up ObjectMapper, e.g.

```
Unirest.config().setObjectMapper(new JacksonObjectMapper());
```

If you already have object mapper configured for your needs, pass it to constructor:

```
new JacksonObjectMapper(yourObjectMapper);
```

There is a separate dependency for object mappers for [Jackson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.konghq/unirest-objectmapper-jackson) or [Gson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.konghq/unirest-object-mappers-gson) implementation

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `body` implementation of `HttpRequestWithBody`:

```
public RequestBodyEntity body(Object body) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = (ObjectMapper) Options.getOption(Option.OBJECT_MAPPER);

    if (objectMapper == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Serialization Impossible. Can't find an ObjectMapper implementation.");
    }

    return body(objectMapper.writeValue(body));
}
```

It seems that passing an objet is ok if an `ObjectMapper` is available